# Fix latency when sending state

Tags: javascript, multiplayer, node.js, phaser, latency

I have a multiplayer game done with [Phaser](http://phaser.io/), which runs in the browser and on a node.js server.

The server is authoritative, every 50ms or so it sends the game state object to all clients. The clients receive the state and update all instances accordingly. The game runs at 60fps, and the physics and AI are the same on clients on server, so if there is no user interaction the game will evolve exactly the same (the next frame on the server will be equal to the next one on the client). This should make sync much easier, but I have a problem:

When the client receives the state from the server, the state is no longer up to date (as there is the latency between server and client).

Here is a drawing:

---

**Server:** State1 -> State2 -> **State3** -> State4 -> State5
................................................***-------------------V**
**Client :** State1 -> State2 -> State3 -> State4 -> <del>State5</del>**State3**

---

So, when the client receives **State3**, it is no longer usable as it has already been at **State3**. This makes the game always rewind a few frames when it receives the update from the server. How can I solve this, taking in account that the same game engine runs on both client and server (so prediction is much easier).

I would try "rendering the game in the past" as I have seen in other cases, but I do not really think I can break **Phaser** physics/render loop connection.

Comment: does the new state from the server overwrite the current client state? or do you "ease in" the new state. say, a position. if you ease it in, latency shouldn't be too visible.

Comment: That's the problem, because I am using Phaser with the p2js physics engine it would be harder to implement my own interpolation. I was just asking if there is somehow possible to start the client game a few states later, so when it receives State3 it actually has to be at State3 (not State5). And yes, for now the client state is over-written by the server state when it is received. I have fixed some issues by not over-writting the state if the state is close enough (this is similar to prediction being close to actual position).

Comment: @Cristy , did you achieve any progress?

Comment: @unknown.0perator I haven't worked on this game that much since this question was posted, but as far as I remember, the game was running pretty smoothly because I made it interpolate to the current position instead of teleport to it (slowly move to the position received from the server) and once it reaches there it extrapolates until the next state is received (the physics engine kicks in and moves all objects with the same logic that exists on the server).

Comment: And this question is actually a bit misleading, as once the client receives "State3" the next states he will receive will actually be usable and should usually match the current client state. So, the game on the client would actually look as the game on the server, but with a small delay, given by the latency.

Comment: @Cristy How do you send game state to all the clients at exact 50ms interval? I use setTimeout in my server update and call the update function itself inside the setTimeout, but I can't emit the state at an accurate 50ms interval. I print out the timestamp at each update and I see the actual update interval varies from 50 - 80 ms.

Comment: @newguy Well, depends on how long it takes to compute the game frame and serialize the game state. Anyway the right way to do it is to also serialize the game time, so when you receive the state on the client-side you know how slow/fast to interpolate towards that state (eg: if the game time of the new state is close to the current game time interpolate faster, otherwise interpolate slower). I don't know if this answers your question

Comment: @Cristy so this can't be fixed on the server side? I know I need to fiddle with interpolation on client side due to network latency but at least I hope that the game state is emitted at a fixed interval. Otherwise the game state is too unpredictable. I have found a solution on reddit which gives me an interval of 47 ~ 53ms based on absolute timing. I think this is the closest I can get for now.

Comment: @newguy Well, if you do something like [this](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) and your game physics are running at 60FPS (16ms) then if you emit the game state every 3 frames you will always emit the game state each `48ms`. Now, 50ms is a very, very small time considering that the network latency can be over 200-300ms. The bad part is that in the browser the protocol is TCP so it's even slower. Mostly what you can do is experiment and see which settings work best (make sure you are testing with network throttling).

Comment: @Cristy But in Node.js `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` can't guarantee game physics to be running at 1000/60 interval. Again I have to do some trick on the game physics update but every so often the interval drifts a bit. I guess this is the downside of using Node.js as the game server.

Comment: @newguy Well, it depends on how long your update loop actually takes. Using `setTimeout` alone might not be enough, you might want to also computed the actual time passed since last update or maybe use smaller `setTimeout` intervals but this would add some overhead.